# Save the rank in the DB

Tags: php, sql

I'm using this query to classify pages for which users vote for :

```
  SELECT p.page_ID , h.point
  FROM pages p
    INNER JOIN history h ON h.page_ID=p.page_ID
  ORDER BY h.point DESC
```

So I know how to display my pages ranking, but I'd like to save the rank of each page in my table. How do ?

Comment: you want to save the rake of each page to the pages table?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have in PHP `$rank` as the rank value and `$pageid` as the `page_ID` you wish to update (and assuming they're both integers not requiring quotes):

```
UPDATE history SET point=$rank WHERE page_ID=$pageid;
```

Or if the page does not already exist in the `history` table:

```
INSERT INTO history (page_ID, point) VALUES ($pageid, $rank);
```